# Preserving fragment state

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my app, I have the following architecture:

```
MainActivity
|_ FirstFragment
|   |_ GridFragment
|   |_ MapFragment
|
|_ SecondFragment
|
|_ ThirdFragment
```

**Please note that:**

- `MainActivity` is using `ActionBarSherlock` and [`SlidingMenu`](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu).
- `SlidingMenu` switches between fragments (`FirstFragment`, `SecondFragment`, `ThirdFragment`).
- `FirstFragment` creates a button into the action bar to switch between **grid** and **map** mode. This is, to switch between its subfragments.

**What I want to achieve**

I need fragments need to preserve its state when switching between them. This is, if I am in `FirstFragment` and then select map mode (show `MapFragment` subfragment), and from the slide menu choose another option and come back, **I should see the map again**. Right now, it's resetting each fragment when selecting its section from the slide menu.

This isn't surprising, as at the moment I am commiting transactions with `new FirstFragment()` when the menu options are pressed.

However, I first tried to have references to each fragment into his parent. For example, `MainActivity` had three fragments members which, when commiting transactions, were checked if exist previously and instantiated if necessary. This worked fine until I added the second level of fragments, then it started throwing exceptions when committing the transaction (saying that the Activity was destroyed).

As you may have noticed, I am far from being an Android expert and need some guidance on this topic.

**How can I preserve fragment states without having a reference for each of them?**

Comment: *...as at the moment I am commiting transactions with new FirstFragment() when the menu options are pressed.* - when the user makes a change in the `FirstFragment` store that change at the `Activity` level a boolean, integer field(or you could store it in a static boolean flag in FirstFragment as you only have two options). When a new instance of FirstFragment gets created make it check the activity or that boolean flag and create the proper nested fragment based on the value of the flag.

Comment: how do you handle second depth fragments (grid and map)? did you use getChildFragmentManager() for managing them? In my case, I managed two -depth tab ( tab in tab ) using getFragmentManager() for first depth tab and getChildFragmentManager() for second depth tab.

Comment: @kingori yes, I am using `getChildFragmentManager()` inside `FirstManager`.

Comment: @Luksprog I did thought about a solution in that direction, but it seems a little bit unnatural: I would have to save map coordinates, if the user did change the initial city among other stuff, and then retrieve it by myself. Anyway, if it doesn't exist a solution where the entire Fragment is restored, I think I will have to go that way.

Comment: I don't think there is another solution because each time you  create a new fragment so there is no state available unless you somehow save it. Probably not the best, but not quite unusual as the newly created fragments would require initialization anyway. You could try to reuse fragment instances so you only attach/detach them but by the fragments you used I would avoid it.

Comment: But the actual question is, do I need to re-create each Fragment when the user tries to open that section?

Comment: Just a wild guess in case you did not have a try: add this line `setRetainInstance(true);` in the onCreateView function of the Fragment class.

Comment: @YoannHercouet I did and I didn't see any difference. Also, that method is not allowed on subfragments.

Comment: Attach and detach fragments from the MainActivity manually. It would help to see how you modify the FirstFragment's content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Next thing I tried after posting the question, was to avoid keeping the fragments in local variables inside its container and using `FragmentManager.getFragmentByTag()` to access them at any given time, but the problem persisted, as `FragmentTransaction.replace()` was destroying the fragments.

**My solution**

As **Luksprog** pointed out in his comment, I had to manage all fragments manually. In order to achieve this, I had to go back to my former approach, where I had local variables for each fragment. Then, `MainActivity` does the following:

- Instantiate its three fragments.

  ```
  this.firstFragment = new FirstFragment();
  this.secondFragment = new SecondFragment();
  this.thirdFragment = new ThirdFragment();
  ```
- Attach the three fragments, and hide all of them except the initial section.

  ```
  getSupportFragmentManager()
      .beginTransaction()
      .add(R.id.content_frame, this.firstFragment)
      .add(R.id.content_frame, this.secondFragment)
      .add(R.id.content_frame, this.thirdFragment)
      .hide(this.secondFragment)
      .hide(this.thirdFragment)
      .commit();
  ```
- To switch content, `SlideMenu` is calling this function:

  ```
  public void switchContent(Fragment newContent) {
      if (newContent != null) {
          getSupportFragmentManager()
          .beginTransaction()
          .detach(this.firstFragment)
          .detach(this.secondFragment)
          .detach(this.thirdFragment)
          .attach(newContent)
          .commit();

          // Restore menu open gesture if map is not present
          if (!(newContent instanceof firstFragment) &&  getSlidingMenu().getTouchModeAbove() != SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN)
              getSlidingMenu().setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);

          // Set menu open gesture if map is present
          if (newContent instanceof firstFragment && firstFragment.currentFragment == FirstFragment.MAP_FRAGMENT)
              getSlidingMenu().setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_NONE);

          getSlidingMenu().showContent();
      }
  }
  ```

Then, the fragments which has subfragments (`FirstFragment`) is doing the same but:

- It's using `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `getSupportFragmentManager()`.
- It's using `show()` and `hide()` to replace content, because when using `detach()` and `attach()` the map wasn't preserving it's coordinates.

Comment: In general this sounds like an antipattern, but indeed it works, and I have found no other solutions to the problem.